# Deploying my app on Heroku using my own database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, data-migration, database

Currently I am deploying my app on a Heroku server. The app is written on Node.js and uses MongoDB as a database source. I'd like to know how I can upload my own database on Heroku without having to use any add-ons or databases provided by Heroku.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708019/how-to-use-your-own-mysql-database-server-with-heroku

Comment: Can I ask you why you don't want to use the addon?

Comment: because it won't synchronize with the original source

Comment: Hmm, ok... But I guess you have to use some kind of remote databasse, because it should make no sence to "upload" a database to heroku (if you mean by that to a dyno) because of Herokus infrastructure and the filesystem. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: maybe I didn't formulate the question well, but I found out that there are some configurations variables and I set them the right values and now it works perfectly. I have a database URL and the variable node_env=production. Now I should mark the question as solved.

Comment: @petrunka this is an old question but I would appreciate the solution you found. Could you add it as an answer. I am having a similar problem with a Nosql DB